# Check size of Rails cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Is there a way to check the size of the Rails cache?

Something in the vein of: `Rails.cache.size => 390 MB`

I assume there's some slight variation between data stores, but right now I'm not sure how to even start to check the disk space a cache is taking up.

Answer (score 19):

that totally depends on your cache store and the backend you use.

this is an example from my heroku instance running memcachier:

```
Rails.cache.stats
# => {"xxx.memcachier.com:11211"=>{"curr_items"=>"278", "bytes"=>"3423104", "evictions"=>"0", "total_items"=>"7373", "curr_connections"=>"7", "total_connections"=>"97", "cmd_get"=>"141674", "cmd_set"=>"7373", "cmd_delete"=>"350", "cmd_flush"=>"6", "get_hits"=>"63716", "get_misses"=>"77958", "delete_hits"=>"162", "delete_misses"=>"188", "incr_hits"=>"0", "incr_misses"=>"0", "decr_hits"=>"0", "decr_misses"=>"0"}}
```

`FileStore` does not have such a method:

```
Rails.cache.stats
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `stats' for #<ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore:0x007ff1cbe905b0>
```

And when running a memcached locally, i get a different result set:

```
Rails.cache.stats
# => {"127.0.0.1:11211"=>{"pid"=>"327", "uptime"=>"517931", "time"=>"1392163858", "version"=>"1.4.16", "libevent"=>"2.0.21-stable", "pointer_size"=>"64", "rusage_user"=>"2.257386", "rusage_system"=>"4.345445", "curr_connections"=>"15", "total_connections"=>"16", "connection_structures"=>"16", "reserved_fds"=>"20", "cmd_get"=>"0", "cmd_set"=>"0", "cmd_flush"=>"0", "cmd_touch"=>"0", "get_hits"=>"0", "get_misses"=>"0", "delete_misses"=>"0", "delete_hits"=>"0", "incr_misses"=>"0", "incr_hits"=>"0", "decr_misses"=>"0", "decr_hits"=>"0", "cas_misses"=>"0", "cas_hits"=>"0", "cas_badval"=>"0", "touch_hits"=>"0", "touch_misses"=>"0", "auth_cmds"=>"0", "auth_errors"=>"0", "bytes_read"=>"48", "bytes_written"=>"30", "limit_maxbytes"=>"67108864", "accepting_conns"=>"1", "listen_disabled_num"=>"0", "threads"=>"4", "conn_yields"=>"0", "hash_power_level"=>"16", "hash_bytes"=>"524288", "hash_is_expanding"=>"0", "malloc_fails"=>"0", "bytes"=>"0", "curr_items"=>"0", "total_items"=>"0", "expired_unfetched"=>"0", "evicted_unfetched"=>"0", "evictions"=>"0", "reclaimed"=>"0"}}
```

Comment: How do I check the FileStore size then?

Comment: @sandre89 Dirty way: `system("du -s #{ Rails.cache.cache_path }")`

Comment: That `du` command may be showing a compressed version if `Rails.cache.options[:compress]` is true.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @phoet's answer, for a Redis cache you can use the following to get a human readable format:

```ruby
Rails.cache.stats["used_memory_human"] #=> 178.32M
```

Where `used_memory_human` can actually be any key that's returned when running an `INFO` command on the redis server.

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `stats' for #<ActiveSupport::Cache::RedisCacheStore:0x000055f2ace84d20>) in 2021

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `memory_store`, you can monkey patch `MemoryStore` class to get the used cache size.

`config/initializers/inspectable_memory_store.rb`

```
module ActiveSupport
  module Cache
    class MemoryStore

      include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

      def size
        number_to_human_size(@cache_size)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now, `Rails.cache.size` will give you the total used cache size

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `FileStore` cache you can sum up the sizes of all cache entries with the following code:

```rb
cache_path = Rails.root.join('tmp', 'cache')
excluded_folders = ['assets', 'bootsnap']
total_size = 0

Dir.glob("#{cache_path}/**/*").each do |file|
  next if excluded_folders.any? { |folder| file.include?(folder) }
  total_size += File.size(file) if File.file?(file)
end

puts "Total Cache Size: #{total_size / 1.kilobyte} KB"
```